# Is there a file-like object in Python/Java that can filter lines based on regex pattern matching?

Tags: java, python, jython

I am running some very chatty programs that emit so many important things that I want to split their output into multiple files based upon patterns in what they are saying.

So, I feel I need a file-like object that can intercept lines that match certain regular expressions and write them to different actual files.  Non-matching lines would pass through to the 'default' file. The [googlenets](http://www.google.com) are not helping.

I imagine myself using it like this:

```
outputFile = FilteringFile('unfiltered-output.txt', 'w')
outputFile.addFilter(re.compile(r'spam'), 'regarding-spam.txt')
outputFile.addFilter(re.compile(r'eggs'), 'regarding-eggs.txt')
```

Now, I can `outputFile.write('...')` and all lines having to do with `spam` will be safely written into only `regarding-spam.txt`, and all lines having to do with `eggs` will be safely written into only `regarding-eggs.txt`.  All those lines having to do with neither `spam` nor `eggs` would pass safely into `unfiltered-output.txt`.  Apart from this internal magic, `outputFile` behaves like an ordinary file.

Does either Python or Java already have such a thing?  If not, how would you go about accomplishing this kind of thing efficiently?  I will accept a solution in either language, as my code is running on Jython.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using [Log4J 2](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#RegexFilter) in Java. You set up a configuration file in `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <RegexFilter regex=".* test .*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

then in Java code, you can do things like:

```
Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();
log.info("Here is some info about a test object: {}", object);
```

Depending on the various appenders and loggers that you've defined in your config file, each line logged gets written to the appropriate files. In this case, our logger is logging messages at severity INFO or higher, and the message matches the RegexFilter, so this line would make it into `logs/app.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is hacky way to do this in Python with the help of stdlib's **logging** module (and it's amazing filtering abilities). Basically you will need to create two separate handlers, and add correct filters to both of them.

Filters need to be implemented by developer and they simply return 1 if the message passes the filtering and 0 if it is not. You can read [more about Filter objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects)  on the official documentation page of the **logging** module.

In following code I've implemented a simple filter that takes a regular expression as one of it's init method arguments and then matches every record to that regex. Unfortunately the code is pretty wordy because of the necessary configuration of logger object.

**multifilelogging.py**

```
import logging
import re

# Creating a filter object that will match records based on supplied regex
class re_filter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self, name='', regex_str=''):
        self.regex = re.compile(regex_str)
        super().__init__(name=name)

    def filter(self, record):
        matched = 1 if self.regex.match(record.msg) else 0
        return matched

# Instantiating the logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

# Creating two handlers
spam_handler = logging.FileHandler("spam.txt")
eggs_handler = logging.FileHandler("eggs.txt")

# Setting a loglevel for them
spam_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
eggs_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Setting a formatter for them
spam_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
eggs_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

# Adding the filters
spam_handler.addFilter(re_filter(regex_str=r'.*spam.*'))
eggs_handler.addFilter(re_filter(regex_str=r'.*eggs.*'))

# Finally, attaching the handlers to the logger
logger.addHandler(spam_handler)
logger.addHandler(eggs_handler)

# This goes to spam.txt
logger.debug("Here's the spam")
# This goes to eggs.txt
logger.info("Here's the eggs")
```

Here's the output:

**spam.txt**

```
2016-05-20 23:16:04,731 - INFO - Here's the spam
```

**eggs.txt**

```
2016-05-20 23:16:04,731 - INFO - Here's the eggs
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it interesting that I got **two** solutions based on logging.  Perhaps I should be logging, instead of writing to `stdout` and `stderr`, but that seems like too big a change right now considering the amount of code involved.

This is what I'm using right now, but I have a nagging feeling that it may be terribly inefficient under certain circumstances.  I am sure somebody out there can do better.

```
'''
For Splitting File Output into Multiple Files
'''

class OutputFileFilter(object):
    '''A (somewhat) file-like object that sends different lines to
    different actual files based upon regular expression matching.

    As you can see, much of the file interface is missing, and
    attempts to use those methods will raise ``AttributeError``.
    '''

    def __init__(self, defaultOutputFile):
        '''Initialize this :class:`OutputFileFilter` with a
        `defaultOutputFile`.

        All lines that do not match any regular expression patterns
        will be written to `defaultOutputFile`.'''

        self.defaultOutputFile = defaultOutputFile
        self.patternOntoFile = {}

    def addPatternAndFile(self, pattern, anotherFile):
        '''Add a regular-expression `pattern` and a `anotherFile` for
        the lines matching that expression.

        The `pattern` will be used in an ``re.search()`` operation.
        If the search result is ``not None``, that is the file that
        will receive the output.'''

        self.patternOntoFile[pattern] = anotherFile

    def write(self, text):
        '''Write some `text` to the appropriate output files.'''

        if '\n' not in text:
            self._dispatchLine(text)
        else:
            for line in text.splitlines():
                self._dispatchLine(line, addNewline=True)

    def writelines(self, lines):
        '''Write an iterable sequence of `lines` to the appropriate
        output files.'''

        for line in lines:
            self._dispatchLine(line, addNewline=True)

    def _dispatchLine(self, line, addNewline=False):
        '''Write a single line of text to the appropriate file.

        This is where the magic happens.'''

        for pattern, anotherFile in self.patternOntoFile.iteritems():
            searchResult = pattern.search(line)
            if searchResult is not None:
                anotherFile.write(line)
                if addNewline:
                    anotherFile.write('\n')
                break
        else:
            self.defaultOutputFile.write(line)
            if addNewline:
                self.defaultOutputFile.write('\n')
```